# How to enforce $\alpha < 0$ and $k \neq 1$ when solving a system of linear equations?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to solve a system of linear equations $$\begin{cases}
\alpha C + \beta &=0 , \\ ( e^{\sqrt{-\alpha}} - k ) A + ( k - e^{-\sqrt{-\alpha}} ) B &=0, \\ ( e^{\sqrt{-\alpha}} - 1 ) A + ( 1 - e^{-\sqrt{-\alpha}} ) B + \sqrt{-\alpha} C - \sqrt{-\alpha} \beta &=0, \\ ( ke^{\sqrt{-\alpha}} - 1 ) A + ( ke^{-\sqrt{-\alpha}} -1 ) B + (k-1) C &=0,\end{cases}$$ for  $(A, B, C, \beta)$. Here $\alpha < 0$ and $k \neq 1$ are constants. I use the command

```
LinearSolve[{{0, 0, \[Alpha], 1}, {E^Sqrt[-\[Alpha]] - k, 
   k - E^-Sqrt[-\[Alpha]], 0, 0}, {E^Sqrt[-\[Alpha]] - 1, 
   1 - E^-Sqrt[-\[Alpha]], 
   Sqrt[-\[Alpha]], -Sqrt[-\[Alpha]]}, {k*E^Sqrt[-\[Alpha]] - 1, 
   k*E^-Sqrt[-\[Alpha]] - 1, k - 1, 0}}, {0, 0, 0, 0}]
```

[image]

Could you explain how to let Mathematica know $\alpha < 0$ and $k \neq 1$? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You have a homogeneous linear system and you are computing a (probably 1 dimensional) basis of the null space. It will likely be easier to compute it as a function of the parameters, and impose the conditions on them after the fact.

Comment: Actually in this case the null space is just the zero vector.

Answer (score 0):

`Assumptions` do not work, `Assuming` does:

```
Assuming[\[Alpha] > 0 && k != 1, 
 LinearSolve[{{0, 0, \[Alpha], 1}, {E^Sqrt[-\[Alpha]] - k, 
   k - E^-Sqrt[-\[Alpha]], 0, 0}, {E^Sqrt[-\[Alpha]] - 1, 
   1 - E^-Sqrt[-\[Alpha]], 
   Sqrt[-\[Alpha]], -Sqrt[-\[Alpha]]}, {k*E^Sqrt[-\[Alpha]] - 1, 
   k*E^-Sqrt[-\[Alpha]] - 1, k - 1, 0}}, {0, 0, 0, 0}]]
```

> `{0, 0, 0, 0}`

Comment: Certainly, $(0,0,0,0)$ is a solution of the system. Can Mathematica handle the case where the system has more than one solution?

Comment: With the command `LinearSolve[{{0}}, {0}]`, Mathematica only returns `{0}`.